# Can I use a weapon that makes noise when there's no room for more noise tokens?

Tags: dead-of-winter

Is it possible to use a weapon making noise if there's no more room for noise tokens on a location? And is it possible to use a weapon making noise in the colony, knowing that you can't put noise token on the colony?

Answer (score 13):

Read the description on the weapon cards. Most of them doesn't make noise. Ones that do, have a clause: "add noise **if possible**". Thus, you don't add noise in the colony or if 4 noise tokens are already present at the location.

[image]